Rank an array of objects by category and value
I am working with a large array in the following format:
// Sample data
const array = [
{country: "Germany", category: "A", value: 300},
{country: "Brazil", category: "A", value: 200},
{country: "Canada", category: "A", value: 200},
{country: "Germany", category: "B", value: 100},
{country: "Brazil", category: "B", value: 400},
{country: "Canada", category: "B", value: 500},
]

and I want to want to rank the values by category and value rank and potentially add an overall_rank without considering the category:
// Expected result
[
{country: "Germany", category: "A", value: 300, rank: 1, overall_rank: 2},
{country: "Brazil", category: "A", value: 200, rank: 2, overall_rank: 3},
{country: "Canada", category: "A", value: 200, rank: 2, overall_rank: 3},
{country: "Germany", category: "B", value: 100, rank: 3, overall_rank: 4},
{country: "Brazil", category: "B", value: 200, rank: 2, overall_rank: 3},
{country: "Canada", category: "B", value: 500, rank: 1, overall_rank: 1},
]

So far I got and overall_rank working, but I am struggling ranking the values by value and category:
array.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.value - a.value;
});

var overall_rank = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0 && array[i].value < array[i - 1].value) {
    overall_rank++;
  }
    array[i].overall_rank = overall_rank;
}

How to move forward?

how did u get overall ranking working with that

Does this answer your question? How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?

@cmgchess thanks for flagging. I forgot the sort function. Just added it, that's how I am getting the overall ranking

To get the rank within the category, you can first use Object.groupBy to split the objects based on their category property, then sort each of the categories separately.


const array = [
  {country: "Germany", category: "A", value: 300},
  {country: "Brazil", category: "A", value: 200},
  {country: "Canada", category: "A", value: 200},
  {country: "Germany", category: "B", value: 100},
  {country: "Brazil", category: "B", value: 400},
  {country: "Canada", category: "B", value: 500},
];
for (const category of Object.values(Object.groupBy(array, o => o.category))) {
  let i = 0, prev;
  for (const o of category.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)) {
    o.rank = i += prev !== o.value;
    prev = o.value;
  }
}
console.log(array);




You could sort each record and assign a unique rank:


const arr = [
  { country: "Germany", category: "A", value: 300 },
  { country: "Brazil",  category: "A", value: 200 },
  { country: "Canada",  category: "A", value: 200 },
  { country: "Germany", category: "B", value: 100 },
  { country: "Brazil",  category: "B", value: 400 },
  { country: "Canada",  category: "B", value: 500 },
];

const sorted = arr.toSorted((a, b) =>
  b.value - a.value ||
  a.category?.localeCompare(b.category) ||
  a.country?.localeCompare(b.country)) ||
  0;

const result = arr.map((record) => ({
  ...record,
  overall_rank: sorted.indexOf(record) + 1
}));

console.log(...result.map(JSON.stringify));
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



Or you could group by value:


const arr = [
  { country: "Germany", category: "A", value: 300 },
  { country: "Brazil",  category: "A", value: 200 },
  { country: "Canada",  category: "A", value: 200 },
  { country: "Germany", category: "B", value: 100 },
  { country: "Brazil",  category: "B", value: 400 },
  { country: "Canada",  category: "B", value: 500 },
];

const grouped = [...arr
  .reduce((acc, record, index) =>
    acc.set(record.value, [...(acc.get(record.value) ?? []), record]),
    new Map())
  .entries()]
  .sort(([a], [b]) => b - a);
  
const result = arr.map((record) => ({
  ...record,
  overall_rank: grouped.findIndex(([value]) => value === record.value) + 1
}));

console.log(...result.map(JSON.stringify));
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



